# Difference between <ComponentName /> and ComponentName()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am just wondering if there is a difference between the way `<SomeComponent>` is added to `<Layout>`. Is one way better than the other or is there a reason to use one and not the other?

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Text> Some Text </Text>
  )
}

<Layout>
  <SomeComponent />
  {SomeComponent()}
</Layout>
```

Comment: I think it's essentially the same thing, someone correct me if I'm wrong. In such cases you conventionally use a <> notation to maintain the html syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<SomeComponent>` is just JSX syntax for `SomeComponent()`. They're the same thing.

And with Props:

```
<Layout>
  <SomeComponent prop1={someVariable} />
  {SomeComponent({prop1: someVariable})}
</Layout>
```